# How to disable Formula Error Correction Prompt?

Tags: vba, excel, alerts

I am not very familiar with VBA and I have to perform a task that involves opening a number of Excel files. These are full of broken links and I don't have the time to change things. As I open each file, 5(!) message windows pop up, one after another, and to get rid of them I have to hit "OK".

One of the "OK" windows is this:
[image]

Wanting to avoid this, I have

1. Opened an empty Excel spreadsheet;
2. Hit Alt+F11 to launch the VBA editor;
3. Pasted the following code

   ```
   Sub Appl_Display_Alert_Ex2()
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      ActiveWorkbook.Close
   End Sub
   ```
4. And then hit F5 to run it.

However, while I thought that this applied to Excel as a whole, I assume it only applies to the single file, because I then went to open one of my broken files and the 5 windows popped up anyway.

Question: **is there a way for me to avoid the "OK" message windows for all Excel files, whatever they are?**

Comment: I'm not sure but probably `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` only applies to VBA. Means when you open the file manually you get the alerts, but when VBA opens the file you don't get the alerts. Try to set this to `False` and then let VBA open the other files ([Workbooks.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel)) and see if the messages are gone.

Comment: I don't have a VBA script for this - not enough time unfortunately.

Comment: Well, If you don't have enough time, then maybe we don't have enough time too.

Comment: What kind of comment is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly advise against doing this, as it's not a good practice - **generally it's better to simply fix the formulas/tables to avoid this error** - but if you absolutely insist on doing this.

You can go to `File -> Options -> Formulas -> Error Checking / Error Checking Rules` and disable whatever checks necessary to avoid this prompt.

[image]

**What I'd however recommend you to do instead, is to closely follow this article [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/fix-excel-found-a-problem-with-formula-references-in-this-worksheet) and fix it the proper way instead!**

Comment: Not enough time. 70+ files to be opened manually, and not enough time to automate the process. Lots of legacy errors which I inherited.

Comment: @FaCoffee Do they really... really.. need to be opened manually? Sounds like something VBA could handle. Though that is an entirely different question than the one here at hand. Either way, good luck with whatever you are trying to do :)